# Allowing a subset of devices' data through

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a dynamic fleet of devices self-registering with IoT Hub and feeding data into Azure Stream Analytics - each device has a uniquely generated ID. I would like to be able to randomly pick 10 of them and output this filtered dataset to Power BI for visualisation purposes. I'm using streaming datasets.

How do I go about constructing this subset...? **WHERE deviceId LIKE** isn't the right approach since the device ID is uniquely generated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use Stream Analytics, and have the list of devices you want to output as reference data somewhere to  augment the stream with.

You could then flag that data from the reference set and use a second Stream Analytics output with a where clause on it.

What benefit will this activity have though? Maybe something like an average of all devices would be better? I don't know what the business driver is :-)

Answer (score 0):

RAND is not directly supported in ASA Query Language, but can be used using JavaScript UDF (User Defined Function).
However we don't recommend to use a random generator in ASA, since it affects the repeatability in recovery scenarios.
Anthony suggestion to use reference data or an aggregate function may be the best option.

Thanks!
JS (Azure Stream Analytics team)